# How to show only a portion of an object based on its relation to another object?

Tags: animation, procedural

------UPDATE-------

This is my current progress. I get the effect of masking half of the object but I suppose I more want to only render the faces that within view, not do a hard clip on them like in the gif above.

[image]

Comment: i downvoted the question because Ben did not show any effort he made to solve this.

Comment: read and consider this: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

if you mean, it should look like this: https://youtu.be/tpeUWpk1okM

then you can achieve this by

1.) adding a track to constraint from sphere to your object (red point)

2.) adding a box with a boolean modifier (intersect)

3.) adding a track to constraint from box to your object

4.) adding a copy location constraint to the box from object

5.) adding a limit distance constraint to sphere

a video tutorial is here: https://youtu.be/pww3BxVsko0

(please be a little bit patient, my internet upload speed is blazingly ...slow... :(

and this is why i love BLENDER - you add just some constraints, combine them and you got a perfect effect which is looking really amazing, without knowing anything about matrix, vertices, scalar product or python or mathematics ;)

UPDATE:

and here is a video where the realization of changing the subdivision surface depending on the location of another object is shown:
https://youtu.be/28SGevbNZKQ

Comment: This is really helpful and almost get's me there!!

What isn't reflected in the images above is that when the objects move their faces animate a bit which is an effect I'd like to achieve. I added a gif to my original post. Any additional feedback would be much appreciated!

Comment: Looking at my source example a bit closer, it looks like the further away the object is the less fidelity it has (less faces and more low poly look) and as it gets closer it increases in fidelity. This is specifically something I'd love to be able to replicate.

Comment: "Normally" people show what they've tried so far. This is a platform where people help u to get further with your tries. You provided nothing from  what you did or tried. This is not a "we do all your work for u" - platform, but a "we help u with what you got so far"-platform. You don't have to mark my answer as correct, but don't expect further help here, although i know the answer for your other questions. And your question was : "How to show only a portion of an object based on its relation to another object?" - and this i answered correctly. Open new question for more wishes.

Comment: I have done a lot of explorations since your response last night (which pointed me in the right direction!) but I don't see a way to add that as a comment so that's why I simply responded in text. I'll update my initial post with my progress so far.

Comment: you didn't get the point. In your initial post you just posted what u want. you did show us nothing at all and did not even write what you researched or tried. And just showing a video is not obviously a proof you did that. And again: i answered your initial question. and again: you don't have to check the answer as right, but good luck someone else helps you!

Comment: and of course you did not read "how to ask" - so here i copy some of it:  Search, and research
Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question? Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and above all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!